# Unable to parse data into JSON after fetching data in Next 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, next.js14

My API request is as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios');

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://nisa-backend-dev.onrender.com/',
  headers: { }
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The response for this when i try on postman is like this:

```
{
    "message": "Hello World!",
    "error": false,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "dateTime": "2024-03-15T18:49:10.682Z"
}
```

When i try to do the same in my Next 14 application, its giving me the following error:

```
Unexpected token 'H', "Hello World!" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5329:19)       
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5300:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1447:9)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5309:7)     
    at async getData (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/page.tsx:14:21)  
    at async Home (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/page.tsx:22:18)
```

My code is as follows:

```
const NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = "https://nisa-backend-dev.onrender.com/";

export const getInit = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL);
        if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
        }

        return res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
}

async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await getInit();
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData()
  console.log({ data })
  return (
    <main>
      Home page
      <br />
      <LinkComponent href="/login">Login!</LinkComponent>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I followed the Next JS documentation to achieve my result:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

I tried using axios and its working perfectly. However it looks like a bandaid solution because from what I hear, Next JS supports fetch for caching and validating the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect follow and use await in res.json()

```
export const getInit = async () => {
try {
    const res = await fetch(NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL, { redirect: "follow" });
    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
}
```